# calling different methods using threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to invoke different methods of class at same time.

I am creating 2 classes: Main- this instantiate object of Function  and Function; this extends thread and has 2 methods.

Main.java

```
package ok;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Welcome to Threading");
        Function f1 = new Function();
        f1.start();
        f1.calling();
        f1.calling2();
    }
}
```

Function.java

```
package ok;

public class Function extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Run");
        for(int y=140;y<170;y++){
            System.out.println(y);
        }
    }

    synchronized void calling(){
        System.out.println("Let the game begin");
        for(int y=40;y<70;y++) {
            System.out.println(y);
        }
    }

    synchronized void calling2(){
        System.out.println("Let the game begin for me");
        for(int y=0;y<40;y++) {
            System.out.println(y);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make the methods `calling()` and `calling2()` work at the same time? 
If I start a thread it goes to run() call and doesn't have any return type. In my program, I need to have return value as a `HashMap`.

Do I need to create two classes which extends Threads and write logic of `calling()`, `calling2()` in run of those two classes?

Please suggest.

Comment: You will need two threads to run two functions at the same time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to assign different methods to different threads in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997596/how-to-assign-different-methods-to-different-threads-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `calling` and `calling2` methods are **synchronized**. The very essence of `synchronized` keyword is to **prevent** methods from executing concurrently. So in order to invoke both `calling` and `calling2` in parallel you need to drop the `synchronized` keyword, at least from the method level.

Then, to invoke two methods at the same time, one `Thread` object is enough - one invocation can be executed in new thread, the other in the "current" thread, like this:

```
Thread thread = new MyThread();
thread.start(); // body of run() invoked in a new thread
thread.run();   // body of run() invoked in this thread, concurrently
```

It's better practice to produce separate `Runnable` objects for such use-cases, though. This has several advantages over the aformentioned approach:

- it's more flexible - as the action is decoupled from the execution and encapsulated in a separate object, it becomes more like "data". If you ever feel the need to change computation strategy - e.g. use thread pool - it's trivial to do so with `Runnable` tasks. Not so with `Thread` extensions.
- it's conceptually more sound, as subclassing a `Thread` suggests specializing its behaviour, while `Runnable`s are more like "task containers" - favor composition over inheritance.
- it's symmetric - no computation is treated differently, it's trivial to change e.g. which one executes where

Last, you seem to want to return something from your methods. For this, you might use a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) - a java concurrency utility class, representing asynchronous computation. In addition to `Runnable` advantages, it can return a value and offers features like cancellation and state querying.

Comment: @ Marcin Los:
Can you elaborate: [b]to invoke two methods at the same time, one Thread object is enough - one invocation can be executed in new thread, the other in the "current" thread. It's better practice to produce separate Runnable objects for such use-cases, though.[/b]

Comment: @Death Metal Edited to include an example

Comment: @ Marcin
Sorry I couldn't do the 
thread.start(); // body of run() invoked in a new thread
thread.run(); 
However, I have implemented two future, which return me hash tables. 
My worry is: that won't be too much of overhead, while handling 468 migs of file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the calls for running the methods inside your run() method.

Then you can just call the start() method and both methods will run. But that does not really solve the problem. What you need to do is create two threads and have each of them run their respective threads.

Comment: @ Hatori Sanso - Thank you for your reply. Yes, having two methods in Run, won't help me as it won't won't have return value. Can you please elaborate on *is create two threads and have each of them run their respective threads. *

Comment: @ Gray - I have seen that, thank you for sharing the link. I am new to threading and dealing with 500 migs of data, which needs to be organized and then dump it into Database. To organize the data, I want to implement threads.