# Threads not working with Laterna

Tags: java, multithreading, terminal, lanterna

I have a Lanterna terminal app.

With threads I would like to fill up a window with different Panels and read key input accordingly.

Using:

```
thread1 = new ModuleThreads(screen,"Locations","addRightPanel");
thread2 = new ModuleThreads(screen,"Commands","addCenterPanel");
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

The first thread shows in the rightPanel the "Locations" menu.
the menu contains:
"press a for exit." The thread works. The menu appears, and pressing a exits the program.

Now the second Thread doesn't appear nor listens to the matching key pressed:"press b to exit."
Also I used reflection to be able to change menu contents easily.(Its a personal project anyway...:))
The problem is that only the first thread1 is shown in the ui.
The reflection just works.
On itself thread2 works just fine. But just as a single thread.

```
public class ModuleThreads extends Thread{

Screen screen;
String myclass,panel;
Class noparams[]={};
Class moduleClass,panelClass;
Class[] paramScreen;
Class[] myPanelClass;
Constructor constructor,moduleConstructor;
Object moduleObject,panelObject;
Method panelGetView,panelMethod,moduleMethod;
Panel mypanel;
private Thread thread1;

public ModuleThreads(Screen screen,String myclass,String panel){

this.screen=screen;
this.myclass=myclass;
this.panel=panel;


//class aanmaken van Screen.class
paramScreen = new Class[1];
paramScreen[0] = Screen.class;
    myPanelClass = new Class[1];
myPanelClass[0] = Panel.class;
thread1 = new Thread(this);
thread1.start();
try{
    moduleClass = Class.forName("app.modules."+this.myclass);
    //package name er voor plakken.
    moduleObject = moduleClass.newInstance();
    moduleMethod = 
    moduleClass.getDeclaredMethod("readInput",paramScreen);
    moduleConstructor = moduleClass.getConstructor();
    panelClass = Class.forName("app.view.MainView");
    constructor = panelClass.getConstructor(Screen.class);
    panelObject= constructor.newInstance(this.screen);
    panelGetView = moduleClass.getDeclaredMethod("getView",noparams);
    panelMethod = 
    panelClass.getDeclaredMethod(this.panel,myPanelClass);


    mypanel =  (Panel) panelGetView.invoke(moduleObject,null);
    panelMethod.invoke(panelObject, mypanel);



    moduleMethod.invoke(moduleObject,this.screen);

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public void start(){

}
@Override
public void run(){

try{


    mypanel =  (Panel) panelGetView.invoke(moduleObject,null);
    panelMethod.invoke(panelObject, mypanel);
    moduleMethod.invoke(moduleObject,this.screen);

}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does only thread 1 or thread 2 appear, and not both, with both key listeners?

Answer (score 1):

1) Why do you override the `start()` method of `Thread` like that :

```
public void start(){    
}
```

By doing it you prevent the `run()` method from being invoked.
From the javadoc :

**void java.lang.Thread.start()**

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls
>   the run method of this thread

2) You start twice each thread.

```
thread1 = new ModuleThreads(screen,"Locations","addRightPanel");
thread2 = new ModuleThreads(screen,"Commands","addCenterPanel");
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

and

```
public ModuleThreads(Screen screen,String myclass,String panel){
...
thread1 = new Thread(this);
thread1.start();
...
```

You should start once your threads. You could remove the `start()` call performed in the `ModuleThreads` constructor as it is more suitable to decide outside the thread when the thread should be started.

Comment: I have applied these changes. I had the code like this before. I end up having the same result. I guess passing the screen are copies of the object and not the same object. So executing these threads makes me have two copies of screen. So I need to have the two threads to modify the same screen object.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution:

[link in using and modifying same object in different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982523/java-access-an-object-in-different-threads)

So instead of:

```
        thread1 = new ModuleThreads(screen,"Locations","addRightPanel");
        thread2 = new ModuleThreads(screen,"Commands","addCenterPanel");
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
```

I would have something like:

```
        Screen screen =  new TerminalScreen(terminal);

       thread1 = new ModuleThreads() 
        { public void run (){screen.updatePanels("Locations","addRightPanel");
                            screen.readInput();
                           }
        };
        thread2 = new ModuleThreads() 
        { public void run (){screen.updatePanels("Commands","addCenterPanel");
                            screen.readInput();
                           }
        };

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
```

I think this principle would do the trick?